# Is it possible to pass a partial view a different model than the model used by the view it is in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel, partial-views

I tried to do it but I get an error saying that model x was expected but y was passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact you can use any class, but it has to match the `@model` declaration of your *partial* view.

Partial View:

```
@model partialViewModel
<h2>@Model.partialViewModelProperty</h2>
```

Main View:

```
@model mainViewModel
<h1>Model.mainViewModelProperty</h1>
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", new partialViewModel()
    {
         partialViewModelProperty = "A title"
    })
```

Comment: how can create and fill partialViewModel model in action and pass it to partial?it works nice but it is hard code

Answer (score 0):

No, that is the point of a **strongly-typed** View.  It requires a certain type.  A partial view would handle this the same as any other view.