# how to pass two model to my views one to partial one to home view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i developed a simple web application on mvc3 and i have one master layout and it contains one partial view and i have a home view in contains that master layout.

i want to pas two model to my view, one model to partial view and one model to home view.

this is may master layout:

```
  @Html.Partial("_PartialMaster")
  @{Html.RenderAction("paction", "Home");}
  <div>
     @RenderBody()
  </div>
```

and my partial view:

```
@model test.Models.MyModel1
<div>
  @Html.ValueFor(m=>m.value1)
</div>
```

my models:

```
public class Model1
 {
    public string value1 { get; set; }
 }

public class Model2
 {
    public string value2 { get; set; }
 }
```

and these are my actions:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {          
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult paction()
    {
        Model2 m2 =new Model2();
        m2.value1="123";
        return PartialView("_PartialMaster",m2);
    }
```

here it works fine and pass model two in partial view and you can use it in partial view but now here i pas model one to my partial view and it works fine but when i want to pass model two into my home view and change home controller to this:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Model1 m1 = new Model();
        m1.value1 = "abc"; 

        return View(m1);
    }
```

it makes error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'test.Models.Model2', but this   
dictionary requires a model item of type 'test.Models.Model'.
```

how can i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my layout just need

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("paction", "Home");}
```

and to pass model to partial need:

```
 public PartialViewResult paction()
    {
        Model2 m2 = new Model2();
        m2.value1 = "123";
        return PartialView("_PartialMaster", m2);
    }
```

now you can pas model to your partial and render it in your main layout and you can use different model in your home action

Comment: This actually fires an additional request to the server just so you know. If you can get both models' values on 1 request then you should avoid using renderAction helper...

Answer (score 5):

Best way to do this is to have a 3rd model AKA ViewModel that contains your other models as properties. So assuming all your models reside in namespace projectName.ViewModels then:

```
namespace projectName.ViewModels
{
   public class ViewModel
   {
      public Model1 ModelA { get; set; }
      public Model2 ModelB { get; set; }
   }
}
```

once you have this you can populate your models in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.Model1 = new Model1 {value1 = "XYZ"};
    model.Model2 = new Model2 {value2 = "ABC"};    
    return View(model);
}
```

and then your index view will take the ViewModel as it's model type:

```
@model = projectName.ViewModels.ViewModel
```

and you can use any of the properties of the model in your Index view, for example:

```
<div>@Model.Model1.Value1</div>
<div>@Model.Model2.Value2</div>
```

and if you need to pass, let's say Model2 to your partial view then all you have to do is:

```
@Html.Partial("_partialViewName", Model.Model2)
```

Make sure your partial view takes in a type of Model2 as it's model:

```
@model = projectName.ViewModels.Model2
```

Comment: @motevallizadeh No problem please upvote and accept if it solved your problem and answered your question... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can include both of the @Model directives at the top of the main page and the partial will still be able to access them I believe.

Comment: Move the @model directive from the partial view into the main view where the partial is being rendered.

Comment: how to pass these two models by one action?i mean index action

Comment: You will return your main view for the action and in that view is where RenderPartial is called on your partial view. The razor file (assuming you are using razor) would then have the @model directives for both models in the main view.

Comment: look at this article it is very close to my answer but i do not know how to dynamically pas this model to that partial in this article create and pas model to partial  by hard code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418925/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-partial-view-a-different-model-than-the-model-used-by-t

Comment: You could use the view bag or combine your data into the main view model and pass the necessary parts to the partial view.